# Lotus Notes subdomain exchange server

Tags: email-server, mx-record, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

We have a notes server at `notesserv01.intra.contoso.com` that processes our regular email, and an exchange server at `exchserv01.intra.contoso.com` for testing purposes.

Lotus Notes email addresses are of the form `name@contoso.com`, Exchange email addresses will be of the form `name@intra.contoso.com`. So, we already made an MX record for intra.contoso.com in our ActiveDirectory DNS server.

When we send emails to `name@intra.contoso.com` from Lotus Notes, it is not delivered to the Exchange server. Instead, Domino server tells us that it could not find that email address in the Notes directory:

> Error transferring to INTRA.CONTOSO.COM; SMTP Protocol Returned a Permanent Error 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table

How do we tell Lotus Notes to send `@intra.contoso.com` emails to the Exchange server?

Comment: I have a question. In the above case two mail servers from different providers are used. How can i know the mx record of a destination server if I don't know the details of a subdomain. Are there any tools to detect the mx record of a sub domain by just knowing the name of public main domain?

Comment: @Shahid If you have a question, please use the big red "Ask Question" button on the upper right corner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Make sure, that "intra.contoso.com" is not in the Global Domain document of the domino server, otherwise it will be very hard to make the domino server send these mails out.

Then create a Foreign SMTP- document for intra.contoso.com. Fill in like this:

> Internet Domain: intra.consoso.com
>   Domain name: ExchangeDomain (Dummy Name, has to be unique)

You don't have to fill out any other field.

Then you create a SMTP- connection document from your domino server.

> Destination Server: DummyExchangeName (only has to be unique, don't use real name)
>   Destination Domain: ExchangeDomain (use value from Foreign SMTP document)
>   SMTP MTA relay host: hostname or IP (in square brackets) of your exchange smtp server

You need to have your server configured to use SMTP for sending mails outside the local internet domain (in the server configuration document) in order for this constellation to work.

Take care: Don't change anything in the configuration document unless you know what you are doing, as otherwise you could cause the complete smtp mailrouting to fail if you do something wrong...